# Orchard CMS Migration - Check if column exists

Tags: orchardcms, database-migration

Is there a standard way to check whether a column already exists in Orchard Migration before doing an altertable add column.

Comment: No. Why would you need that?

Comment: Due to some over-zealous re-factoring of the migration code, some updates that were applied to dev environment didn't get applied to Prod environment - Human Error. I prefer to make this change via Migration without writing a script to update the database [currently due to limited access this is a slower process.]

Comment: There is a lot that can happen if the database is not in the state that the migration code expects. You should fix the environment that is in an inconsistent state, instead.